# Is there a forum for manually set nonograms?

Tags: nonogram

I've been getting really into nonograms lately. However, I can't get a great source for difficult nonograms.

One app which I play on generates puzzles, which are decently tough, but never really require any thinking, just scratchwork. And I've got that down to a science by now.

The other app which I play on relies on user-created nonograms, but to be quite frank, most of those just plain suck :/. If you sort by "difficulty," you just get these massive 30x30 puzzles that aren't hard, just boring.

This might be a bad question. For sudoku, I had a similar problem. The apps I was on were just feeding me randomized puzzles solvable with naive techniques. Then I found logic-masters.de. I think, though, the sudoku setting community only exists because the ruleset of sudoku affords advanced techniques to set incredibly probing puzzles. Maybe, because nonograms have a simpler rule set, there just aren't that many cool solving techniques to manipulate as a setter, so there's just no setting community for them.

I can't find much of anything on the topic, so anything is welcome!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't offer recommendations, sorry. They just don't fit with our format, which expects questions to have stable answers, instead of an open-ended list which will likely change significantly over time.

Comment: I know one such Web site. [Here.](/)

Comment: @msh210 A lot of the posts on the nonogram tag are 1. help me with this nonogram; 2. insanely big nonogram that relies on size for difficulty; 3. variant.
Not what I'm looking for :/

Comment: Try [https://www.puzzle-nonograms.com/](https://www.puzzle-nonograms.com/). I haven't done their nonograms but their tapas seem to be man-made with pleasing symmetry and satisfying deductions.